# In svn, how do I obtain the branch name that a specific tag/label is on?

Tags: svn, version-control

In svn, how do I obtain the branch name that a specific tag/label is on ?

In a system with hundreds of branches and thousands of labels, this becomes important.

I am hoping some sort of a command like:

**svn http://REPOSITORY branchof TAG**

Thanks

Comment: Why have you tagged this with `git`?

Comment: Do you have a working copy and would you like figure the branch name? Could you provide a simple example what do you want?

Comment: The repository I am working with has over 800 branches and 35000 tags.  As you can imagine, a command such as the one I am asking becomes crucial.  When our customers report a bug, as part of the debug dump, we obtain the tag/label name.  We then try to check out the BRANCH to which this tag belongs.  This is because the branch will have moved on and the tag may be much older than the head of the branch.  It is for this reason that I would like to find out the BRANCH name, given the TAG.

Comment: Is this question correctly tagged? In Subversion, tags and branches are just a naming convention, not a builtin feature, so you just need to read current path. For this very reason, a given item can't belong to a tag and a branch simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

1. Branches and tags are separate independent trees inside SVN-repo (with "default" layout), i.e. in common case tags don't belongs to branches
2. If tag was created in *proper* style (recommended, but not mandatory) with `svn cp`, you can detect "originated from" branch, if'll use `svn log -v` for the tag

From [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html):

> In addition to the action codes which precede the changed paths, svn
> log with the --verbose (-v) option will note whether a path was added
> or replaced as the result of a copy operation. It does so by printing
> (from COPY-FROM-PATH:COPY-FROM-REV) after such paths.